# ESP32 subscription problem to the MQTT topic

Tags: mqtt, project, iot, esp32, arduino-ide

I used two ESP32 boards one having the publish code and the other one having the subscribe code.

The publish code ESP32 publishes the data to the topic - room 1. And the subscriber esp32 code subscribes to the room 1 topic.

Data is published from the esp32 side with no problem but at the subscriber end the esp32 unable to get the data. it automatically gets disconnected and reconnects whenever the data is published or trying to get the data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Karthikeya Sri, welcome to Stack Overflow. Without your code we have no idea what you're actually doing. Describing code is not helpful, sharing code is. Please edit your question to include a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the problem, both the publishing and subscribing code. Also please let us know what broker you're using. Finally, please don't post images of output - images can't be searched and are difficult for people who use screen readers for assistance. Instead, edit the question and copy and paste the messages into it.

Comment: Just a wild guess (due to lack of info). Are you using the ClientId `ESP32Client` on both units? If so that will be the problem (when a client connects the broker will [disconnect existing connections with the same ID](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718032))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.